# Xamarin forms - error loading PCLCrypto with linking, other errors otherwise

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, pcl-crypto

Getting the following error if I attempt to build with "link SDK only"

Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'PInvoke.BCrypt, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e300f9f87f04a7a'

If I change it to don't link, the rest of my app now has problems.

IS there another way to do an SHA hashing on Xamarin iOS?  I'm injecting my encryption, so not a problem to use iOS only libaries.

Comment: Pay attention to your description, as SHA is for hashing, not for encryption.

Comment: Updated question to say hashing

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround - since my cryptography is injected, I was able to discard PCLCrpyto and just use System.Security.Cryptography instead.